# "Too many levels of symbolic links" error when using systemd

Tags: systemd, automount

I have following line in /etc/fstab:

```
sami@lelu.local:/home/sami /mnt/node fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,users,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/home/sami/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,reconnect 0  0
```

If I enable systemd automounting, by running:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start mnt-node.automount
```

`ls /mnt/node` gives:

```
ls: cannot access '/mnt/node/': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

However, the mount works just fine if I instead mount the drive with command:

```
mount /mnt/node
```

What I am doing wrong with systemd? I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The automount is done by root user. /home/root/.ssh/known_hosts needs to have target machine id. Otherwise the mount will fail and give these error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bug, see ["Too many levels of symbolic links” error when using systemd to mount sshfs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1902891).

I was also struggling with this error. Be aware that reason for this error can be completely different. No record in `known_host` file, wrong user (I have typo error), or it may be something else.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1175291)